# Pip stopped working on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, python, pacman, pip

when trying to use Pip on my Arch system I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import getLogger
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 37, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pep517 import Pep517HookCaller
ImportError: cannot import name 'Pep517HookCaller' from 'pep517' (/home/krystian/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pep517/__init__.py)
```

I have mixed Arch packages with Pip packages which I shouldn't do, but now executing Pip outside of virtual environment shows this error and I can't uninstall these packages. I can still use Pip in virtual environments and manage Python packages through pacman.

Python version:  3.10.6

Comment: Could you elaborate on "I have mixed Arch packages with Pip packages"? Did you upgrade/install Pip packages outside of virtual environments? If so, did you do so by using `sudo`?

Comment: @telometto Yes, I used `sudo` when installing Pip packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue wasn't related to me installing Pip packages with `sudo`, but it was a corrupted `pep517` package in my user environment in `~/.local/lib/python3.10`. Removing the package without using Pip by deleting `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pep517/` fixed the issue. Remember to backup `site-packages` directory before doing that!

Comment: Perfect! I'm glad you managed to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to reinstall the package first:

```
sudo pacman -S python-pip     # reinstalls pip
which pip                     # checks the location of pip
pip install -U pip            # DO NOT RUN AS SUDO! Upgrades pip
which pip                     # check the if the path is the same as previously
hash -r                       # clears bash cache
which pip                     # path *should* now be /usr/local/bin/pip
sudo reboot                   # reboots the machine
```

If you're lucky, you didn't screw up other packages and everything will work again. If not, @ me and we'll try to sort you out.

---

**EDIT:**

2. Since option one did not work, try this:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip   # removes the pip installed using pip
```

Close the terminal, reopen it, and check if `pip` works. Should you get any errors with the above command, just proceed with the steps below

3. Remove the system package:

```
pacman -Rsn python-pip        # removes the package, unrequired deps, and their configuration files
whereis pip                   # check that pip has been completely removed
```

If pip results to be still present on the system, you might have to try and run the command in step 2 with `sudo`, and then repeat the steps in step 3.

4. If `pip` has been successfully removed:

```
pacman -S python-pip          # installs the package
```

Check if `pip` works.

5. Last resort: if none of this works, you might have to set your path to point to the new `pip` install's location (e.g. `alias pip="/usr/local/bin/pip"`), which is just a dirty workaround. Otherwise, I'm not really sure on what to do; you might have to reinstall the OS.

Comment: the location of `pip` is `/usr/bin/pip`, when executing `pip install -U pip` I get the error from the original question.

Comment: @user18686221 I've updated the post.

Comment: I fixed the issue the other way, (read my answer). Thanks for helping anyways.